# how to check null value in grep command using in shell script?

Tags: centos, grep

In shell script in centos, i write following 2 lines

```
cmdread="Myprogram"
kill -9 `ps ax | grep $cmdread `
```

But some times when manually myprogram stopped then my shell script give me warning that nothing to kill.
So how to check like following

```
if(by grep myprogram's pid != null){
kill it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose, you must pass your program's PID to kill command, something like this:

```
cmdread="Myprogram"
_PID=`ps ax | grep $cmdread | grep -v grep | awk '{print$1}'`

if [[ "x$_PID" != "x" ]]
then
    kill -9 $_PID
fi
```

**UPDATE**

I add `grep -v grep` to my code, although without it, my code will run ok because we can pass multiple PID to `kill` command.

Answer (score -2):

For a safer process management I would use the proper reserved variable `$!` or `pgrep` if you have it on CentOS.

E,g

```
#!/bin/sh
cmdread=$(myprogram)
mypid=$!

kill -0 $mypid && printf '%s\n' "My process is stil alive"
kill $mypid
```

Using pgrep
`kill $(pgrep programname)`

Using grep `if ps -ef | grep '[p]rogramname' | grep -q programname; then pkill programname; fi`

Please see the following link http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement for a better understanding about Process Management.

Comment: Wrong way. `$!` refer to PID of last background process ID.

Comment: Sure that's why I provided a few options. The first one is to show how you can get the process id of the program you just ran and store it in a variable. You then can decide what to do with it. Your use of back-ticks is Wrong though.

Comment: Your way to get the process id of the program is wrong. Remember, `$!` is the PID of last background process. Thinking what is background process? And I don't think using back-ticks is wrong. Do you try my code?

Comment: @Gnouc I don't want to argue with you. I know many people who stick with their conservative ideas and they think !sh or bash has not developed through past years. Your code has a lot of flaws. Using awk in this case is pretty much useless since you are invoking another process without a reason. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes?highlight=%28back%29|%28ticks%29  about back-ticks.